# Count alphabetic to numeric and numeric to alphabetic transitions

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I have some data, now I have to count the number of transitions from alphabetic to numeric OR from numeric to alphabetic.

```
dd <- c(text="S4FDD-S4DF5D_S54F4SDF4","eDC54E_EG5SF3543+TDX32RF","CVB5+5VN7NLC2_3LM70LCM8","1VPLF3LPD5P6OK7POD8KP9OASD9POA0")
```

Eg. in `dd[1]`:

```
S4FDD-S4DF5D_S54F4SDF4 == 6 (Alphabetic to number Count)
                                          & 
                       == 5 (Number to Alphabetic Count)
```

I tried by using this function, but failed :

```
stri_count_boundaries(dd, type="character")
```

Comment: `6 alpha to number count, 5 number to alpha count` ... can you explain what exactly this is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option using `lengths` + `gregexpr`:

```
> lengths(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]\\d+",dd))
[1] 6 4 5 8

> lengths(gregexpr("\\d+[[:alpha:]]",dd))
[1] 5 3 4 8
```

Comment: There is no need for `regmatches`: `lengths(gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]\\d", dd))` and `lengths(gregexpr("\\d[[:alpha:]]", dd))` will do it already.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly you want to count how many times you encounter an alphabet followed by a number and vice - versa.

You can use `str_count` here :

```
library(stringr)
str_count(dd, '[A-Z]\\d')
#[1] 6 4 5 8

str_count(dd, '\\d[A-Z]')
#[1] 5 3 4 8
```